# ruby: thrift error - expected protocol id -126 but got 60

Tags: ruby, thrift

I'm using ruby 2.1.2 to stress test a java service as follows:

```
(begin thread)
url = "http://service.ops.net/api"
transport = Thrift::HTTPClientTransport.new(url)
protocol = Thrift::CompactProtocol.new(transport)
client = MyService::Client.new(protocol)
transport.open()

client.<somefunctioncall>
(end thread)
```

...

```
(join thread)
(exit and begin next pass)
```

This is called with a mix of valid and semi-valid params. This works ok as long as I only call one endpoint. If I thread out the calls to hit > 1 endpoint at a time (IE call two different functions from different threads) I start seeing exceptions like so:

> `read_message_begin': Expected protocol id -126 but got 60 (Thrift::ProtocolException)

I can't find a reasonable reference to know what this is telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is telling you that the data could not be deserialized, because they look corrupted. However, that does not mean that they really are corrupted.

A very likely reason for this situation is that client and server do not use the exact same transport & protocol stack.

A typical mistake to produce such a situation is to use `TFramedTransport` on one end, while the other end does not. Thrift Transports may add (and expect) additional data to the data on the wire, and especially `TFramedTransport` does this by adding a 4-byte header which contains the frame size.

It is worth mentioning that some server types implicitly expect the client to use `TFramedTransport`. So if you checked both ends and compared the protocol and transport stack used, this may be another reason.

Comment: The message is returned somewhat randomly. So the implication is that data is getting corrupted in a non-systematic fashion?